# Android RecyclerView LayoutManager - 1st item one column, rest of items as rows in 2nd column

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

Is it possible to layout RecyclerView items with some Layout Manager as on the picture?
1st column is 1st item, rest of items as rows in 2nd column?
[image]

Comment: i think you can use spansizelookup in recycler view if no idea you search it google

Answer (score 0):

With your RecyclerView Setup, this is unfortunately not possible. But you could achieve the Image up top als follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity2">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#673AB7"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndtOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your `RecyclerView` you can create a `CustomAdapter` that displays your Entries as `CardView Rows`. Then you determine the Average of your Contents and display them on the left. This is also far more reliable, beacuse you can determine the contents of the `CardView` without having conection to the `RecyclerView`. If you want to have everthing scrollable, you can wrap the LinearLayout in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but I do know this solution. What I need is to still be able to serve all data from one Adapter.

Comment: RecyclerView is still a One-Dimensional List. You Could Create The Views Programatically but is is impossible with one RecyclerView. Still the solution is relevant to your problem.